# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{e^x+x^n}=1-\frac{1}{e}$?

Tags: analysis

How to prove $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{e^x+x^n}\ \mathrm{d}x=1-\frac{1}{e}$$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ n\geq 2 $, we have : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}}&=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}}+\int_{1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}}\\ &=1-\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}-\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n}}{\mathrm{e}^{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}}\end{aligned}

Since : $$ \left|\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n}}{\mathrm{e}^{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x}\right|\leq\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}}=\frac{1}{n+1}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

And : $$ \left|\int_{1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}}\right|\leq\int_{1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{n}}}=\frac{1}{n-1}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Then $ \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n}}{\mathrm{e}^{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x} $, and $ \int_{1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}} $ both approaches $ 0 $ as $ n $ goes to $ +\infty $, Thus : \begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}+x^{n}}}}=1-\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: explain the integral-limit exchanges in$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{e^x+x^n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{e^x+x^n}=\int_0^1e^{-x}dx+\int_1^\infty0dx.$$